# Django in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: django, visual-studio-2010, azure, visual-studio-2012

I have Visual Studio 2012 in my machine. I just downloaded the [Windows installer provided on this page](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/). When I ran it, it is showing that it can install Python tools and some other things for Visual Studio 2010 (in addition to Azure SDK).

**Question:** Will this installer and these tools work on Visual Studio 2012 too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NO,

But when you open the Web Platform Installer (PI) from the mentioned link, you shall be able to see an option for the same tools/sdk for Visual Studio 2012. What is explicitly named "for VS 2010" will not run on VS 2012.

Comment: Thank you. I am able to find the installer here: http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx. The one on the above link starts Azure setup automatically. 

One thing, Python tools for 2010 adds a comparatively big installation of "Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Integrated) (Despendency)" which does not appear in Python tools for 2012. What effect will this have? Not really able to understand its description here, thought it says it works on VS 2010 and above: http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=115

Comment: I think I figured out why that extra install was coming. It was coming because I didn't have VS 2010 installed.